# How to properly download and install packages in Go?

Tags: html, go, go-packages

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong, I look up steps online what to do and they all tell me to just go to CMD, type in `go get ___` and then just import the github link into my file but I constantly get the `could not import` error in VS Code.

I am trying to parse some HTML code that I get from a response and I need the `"golang.org/x/net/html"` to be able to do things. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set up your project (does it have a `go.mod` file)? If not, you need to run `go mod init projectname`. VSCode gets confused when no `go.mod` file is present, and that file should be in the top directory you opened, it doesn't handle them in subdirectories

Comment: And you should run the `go get ...` command in the same directory where `go.mod` is, that way the package is added as a project dependency. Also maybe see [this](https://golang.org/doc/code)

Comment: @xarantolus Creating the mod file seems to have solved my issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are not following https://golang.org/doc/#getting-started. It is basically dead simple. Just set up your module _properly_ (i.e. as explained in the documentation, no shortcuts, no being clever). The run `go get golang.org/x/net/html` and add `import "golang.org/x/net/html"` to your code. Note that you neither have to "download" nor "install" remote packages. After `go get and import everything is done automatically by the go tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use go modules to manage dependencies.

First you initialize your module with `go mod init ProjectName`. Then when you build your project with `go build` it will find and download missing packages to
module cache directory which is `~/go/pkg/mod`.

You can use `go mod tidy` also.

For more information:
[Go Modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules)

Comment: Is it possible for multiple versions of the same package to coexist in `~/go/pkg/mod`?

Comment: yes, it is possible.